# SSRS 2008 R2 - Export as PDF - Save/Cancel, No Open Dialog

Tags: reporting-services, opendialog

Hopefully this will be pretty simple!  I've googled around but apparently I'm the only person in existence with this issue.  When I go to Export my report as a PDF, a dialog box opens that only has options for Save and Cancel.  I want either:

1. An Open option on that window so the report opens in whatever PDF viewer
2. The report to open automatically AFTER the user saves it as whatever filename they want.

Note that I don't want it to save automatically, but provide them some option to open it AFTER they've saved it.

Comment: Isn't this determined by your browser (type/version/settings) ?

Comment: Is it?  I couldn't get it to show up in the Preview window in BIS either.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is based on the users browser, and has little or nothing to do with SSRS.